# Raising ValidationError from django model's save method?

Tags: python, django

I need to raise an exception in a model's save method. I'm hoping that an exception exists that will be caught by any django `ModelForm` that uses this model including the admin forms.

I tried raising `django.forms.ValidationError`, but this seems to be uncaught by the admin forms. The model makes a remote procedure call at save time, and it's not known until this call if the input is valid.

Thanks, Pete

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's currently no way of performing validation in model save methods. This is however being developed, as a separate model-validation branch, and should be merged into trunk in the next few months.

In the meantime, you need to do the validation at the form level. It's quite simple to create a `ModelForm` subclass with a `clean()` method which does your remote call and raises the exception accordingly, and use this both in the admin and as the basis for your other forms.

Comment: django has been bumming me out lately. I went with this approach, but I'm not satisfied. Code that modifies a model does not belong in a clean method.

Comment: Just checking in, has this branch you talked about been merged in yet?

Comment: It's part of Django 1.2: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

Comment: Currently (Django 1.4) there is a way of performing validation in model save methods. `def save(self, *args, **kwargs):\ self.full_clean()\ super(YourModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`. I created a mixin for that: https://gist.github.com/glarrain/5448253

Answer (score 15):

Since Django 1.2, this is what I've been doing:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    <...model fields...>

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if <some constraint not met>:
            raise ValidationError('You have not met a constraint!')
        super(MyModel, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)

    def full_clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.clean(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This has the benefit of working both inside and outside of admin.